# 'Could not find source file at index.ios.js' when I run 'react-native bundle --minify'

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm trying to submit my react native to the app store.  When I run `react-native bundle --minify` from the root folder of my project I get the following error:

```
Building package...

/AppName/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
            ^
NotFoundError: Could not find source file at index.ios.js
    at /AppName/node_modules/react-native/packager/react-packager/src/DependencyResolver/DependencyGraph/index.js:169:15
    at tryCallOne (/AppName/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
    at /AppName/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:103:15
    at flush (/AppName/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/promise/node_modules/asap/raw.js:50:29)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  The index.ios.js needs to be in the root/main directory.  I had it in a directory I created.